# Sending a file through a socket in C

Tags: c, sockets

I got a task at school to write an FTP program in C language (for Linux). I got all the basic functionality working in no time (ls, cd), but I'm having troubles with the file transfer part. I use sendfile to send the file over the socket like this:

```
int fd = open(temp, O_RDONLY);  
int rc = sendfile (client_fd, fd, &offset, statbuf.st_size);
```

I can't seem to figure out how to receive this file on the client end. I tried it like this for debugging:

```
while( (i = read(sock, message, MSG_LEN - 1)) > 0 ) {

    message[i] = '\0';
    printf("%s", message);
}
```

This does a good job at printing out text files, but if I try to send binary files, for example, it just prints out the beginning of the binary file and hangs at the read() part (since there's nothing coming from server, I think).

I appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: Maybe try sendfile again, with the socket descriptor being the input and a file open for writing as output...?

Comment: BTW / binary files can contain 0 bytes that C-style functions like printf can mistake for ASCIIZ NUL terminators, as well as other values that correspond to ASCII control codes for clearing the screen, moving the cursor etc..  You should print the file content byte-by-byte in hexadecimal or use some other way to make it human-readable and terminal compatible.

Comment: Or use fwrite(message, 1, i, stdout) and redirect the output of your program to a file from the shell

Comment: rc is the size of the sent file after calling sendfile().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to shutdown the writing side of the socket after sending the file, so that the receiver knows the end of the file has been reached:

```
shutdown(client_fd, SHUT_WR);
```

(`shutdown()` is used instead of `close()`, so that you can find out if the other side successfully received the whole file or not).

Your reading side then will see end-of-file (`read()` returning 0), at which point it should `close()` its end of the socket.  The server will then see end-of-file, and it can close its socket too (and record a successful transfer).

Comment: That didn't exactly help, it still transfers files like I described in the first post, but now if I try to give any other commands after 'get', I get an error saying 'broken pipe'.

Comment: I searched around and found that some suggest using recv(). Would you guys suggest read() or recv()?

Comment: Thank you for your answer and you other guys for the suggestions! The problem was that I tried to fork() my program before sending the file, apparently I didn't to it correctly, so that messed everything up. It works now.